# MySQL query - multiple having statements not working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use the following query, and if it only has one `having` statement it works as expected. If I add the second `having` statement it does not work.

```
SELECT candidate.first_name, 
 candidate.last_name, 
 qualification.code, 
 property.value AS funding_band_value, 
 qualification.funding_band,
 property.value AS qualification_level_value,
 qualification.qualification_level_id
FROM candidate_qualification, candidate, qualification, property
WHERE candidate_qualification.candidate_id=candidate.id and
candidate_qualification.qualification_id=qualification.id
HAVING funding_band_value = (select property.value from property where qualification.funding_band=property.id) and
HAVING qualification_level_value = (select property.value from property where qualification.qualification_level_id=property.id)
```

Could someone explain why this doesn't work and how I should do this.

Answer (score 1):

HAVING acts similarly to WHERE or GROUP BY.  You reference it once to start using it and combine multiple statements with AND or OR operators.  An in depth look at the query parser might give you a more explicit answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need HAVING here, just use AND so it is part of your WHERE clause.

The subqueries are not necessary, those tables are already joined.

Something like this should be closer to what you want:

```
SELECT c.first_name, 
    c.last_name, 
    q.code, 
    p.value AS funding_band_value, 
    q.funding_band,
    p.value AS qualification_level_value,
    q.qualification_level_id
FROM candidate_qualification cq 
INNER JOIN candidate c ON cq.candidate_id=c.id 
INNER JOIN qualification q ON cq.qualification_id=q.id
INNER JOIN property p ON q.funding_band=p.id
    and q.qualification_level_id=p.id
```

Comment: I tried that initially, however since funding_band_value and qualification_level_value are aliases they can't be used in the WHERE clause......?

Comment: You don't use the alias, you use the original column name, as I have done (moved to ON clause).